# Размер базы в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Добрый день!

Есть задача ограничить размер базы данных MongoDB. Дабы зафиксировать используемое дисковое пространство.

Как это сделать?

Comment: `capped collection` не спасают?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/command/convertToCapped/

Comment: Надо попробовать
Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Можно для базы сделать отдельный раздел в файловой системе ОС.